# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Error when creating environment. "There are no instances. Unable to assume role XXXXX."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to understand how to use AWS Beanstalk. But I'm struggling to find out the proper policies to make it work when creating Service Roles and Instance Profiles. It's a ruby application.

This is my error when creating an environment. Before I had another error about Managed Updates, which was solved after adding the right policy.

> Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Warning.
> Initialization in progress (running for 2 minutes). There are no
> instances. Unable to assume role
> "arn:aws:iam::149413950731:role/elasticbeanstalk-admin-role-services".
> Verify that the role exists and is configured correctly.

I tried rebuild the environment after updating the roles, still having the same problem.

I'm using a user with PoweruserAccess.

This is the list of roles:
[image: Roles]

Here are the Service Role policies selected:
[image: Service Role]

And the Instance Profile:
[image: Instace Profile]

Comment: Most likely the trust relationship is wrong, you apparently allow EC2 to assume it but should probably allow elastic beanstalk to do it.

Comment: @luk2302 It was exactly that. Very specific and the closest thing that I found explaining something like it about "Service-linked role", which was not very clear if could be used in this scenario.

Comment: Please check this detailed answer to ensure that iam role (service role and instance profile) required for the Elasticbeanstalk to work properly are configured correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77743069/12326605

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, I went to IAM Roles, after entering the specific role related to the error message, I edited the principal inside the Trusted Entity.

Changed the "Principal: Service:" to `elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com`

Before was `ec2.amazonaws.com`

[image]

Thanks to @luk2302 for giving the tip.

Comment: +1 for me i had to use both elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com and ec2.amazonaws.com. ->    ```.... "Service": [ "ec2.amazonaws.com", "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com" ] ....```